# Very strange MySQL timeouts occurring on just one developer machine

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm not optimistic about getting an answer to this one, since it's such a weird and seemingly machine-specific issue, but I'm posting in the hopes that someone else has figured this one out.

I'm developing an application in C# using Visual Studio and the MySQL.Data ADO.Net driver (version 6.9.8) for database access. Twice, I've run into a situation where very simple SQL queries that worked only moments before start timing out. From that point forward, they never succeed again -- but only on my machine. Every other query in the application (and there are hundreds) works fine, but the one query, even if I change it slightly, never works again. If I push the code and another developer runs it, the code works perfectly on his machine.

As an example of how simple these queries are, here's the one I'm most recently having issues with:

```
SELECT * FROM user_preferences WHERE (user_id=@user_id) LIMIT 1
```

The table I'm selecting from has only 1 row and 4 columns. It couldn't be simpler. While the query is waiting to time out, it does not appear in the process list for MySQL, so I have to assume that either it never made it to the server or the server returned instantly and the MySQL connector is just failing to return the response. I'd like to figure out which, but I doubt it would make a difference either way.

So to summarize, that query worked fine this morning. I changed nothing except some unrelated code, and it briefly started returning no data. I started debugging it, and now it just times out. Another developer runs the code, and it works perfectly.

I'm at a complete loss, here. Short of figuring this out, I fear I'm going to have to re-image my laptop, and I'd really like to avoid that if at all possible. Any help would be appreciated, though like I said, it's probably quite a shot in the dark.

Edit: The C# code in question:

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionSettings.GetConnectionString()))
                {
                    await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
                    using (var reader = await MySqlHelper.ExecuteReaderAsync(connection, sql.Query.ToString(), cancellationToken, sql.Parameters.ToArray()))
                    {
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken))
                        {
                            readerAction(reader);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code? like where do you call this query?

Comment: What is the exact exception you are getting? There are two timeouts, one is db connection time out and another is command timeout. See if the db connects first, then try setting Command.CommandTimeout while executing the query. Also you can try running the same query from MySql workbench.

Comment: Editing to add some of the code.

Comment: If I take the query contained in the "sql" var and paste it into Workbench, it works fine. And it worked fine this morning using the code you see here. Nothing changed except code that had nothing to do with any of this. I reverted to this morning's code, and it doesn't work, either.

Comment: I just re-ran it to find the exception, and the first time it didn't even throw one. It just returned nothing. I ran it again, and this time it waited the same amount of time and threw a MySQL exception saying "Fatal error encountered during command execution." Several inner exceptions later, and I get "Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

Comment: That code manages hundreds of other queries just fine, and this one worked fine this morning. It really can't be about the code. There really has to be something wrong with the configuration, libraries or hardware on my laptop, I think.